# How to translate an UPDATE WHERE IF @@ROWCOUNT == 0 query from MS SQL to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query in the following form:

```
UPDATE TableName SET some="1", fields="two" 
WHERE some_condition="true" 
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO TableName(some, fields) VALUES ("1", "two");
```

This query was written in MS SQL but I'd like to translate it to MySQL. I've looked up several refs that say to replace @@ROWCOUNT with [ROW_COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) but I'm not sure what to do.

Any ideas of how to translate queries like this from MS SQL to MySQL?

Comment: what exactly is the criteria `some_condition="true"` ? may be it can be rewritten using  [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way of handling this would be something like....

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableName WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
          WHERE some_condition= "true" )
   BEGIN
        UPDATE TableName 
           SET some    = "1"
             , fields = "two" 
        WHERE some_condition= "true" ;
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TableName(some, fields) VALUES ("1", "two");
   END
```